# How to require an element based on a 'type' attribute value?

Tags: xml, xsd, jaxb, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I'm trying to build a XSD for the below XML and I'm using JAXB to unmarshal to Java Object with validation.

The validation rule is that the first 2 elements in `<JobParam>` which are `type = jobType` and `type = customer` are required. All others within `JobParam` are optional.

How do I create an XSD for this?

```
<job>
    <jobName>core</jobName>
    <jobParams>
         <jobParam type="jobType">Scheduler</jobParam>
         <jobParam type="customer">Alphabet</jobParam>
         <jobParam type="mode">music</jobParam>
      </jobParams>
</job>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot express your validation rule in XSD 1.0.  You would have to do it in Java against your JAXB-created objects, or move to XSD 1.1 where you could use assertions or conditional type assignment.

However, the best solution would be to fix your XML design:

- There's no need to repeat the parent name in the children's names. [**minor**]
- If element types are a part of the name rather than an attribute value, simple XSD 1.0 occurrence constraints can be used to represent your validation rule. [**major**]

Here are the above improvements made to your XML:

```
<job>
    <name>core</name>
    <params>
         <type>Scheduler</type>
         <customer>Alphabet</customer>
         <mode>music</mode>
     </params>
</job>
```

Two other improvements you might consider:

1. Drop the `params` wrapper, promoting its children to be children of `job`.
2. Add back a `customParams` wrapper if you really must support parameters not known at XSD design time.

For example:

```
<job>
    <name>core</name>
    <type>Scheduler</type>
    <customer>Alphabet</customer>
    <customParams>
       <customParam type="mode">music</customParam>
    </customParams>
</job>
```

This can trivially be represented along with your validation rule regarding `customer` and `mode` via basic occurrence constraints in XSD 1.0.

Comment: Thanks. I wish I could change the xml and I agree with your suggestion. But that's quite not possible at this time. The client users of this xml is not willing to update it. Today I handle these validation on Java objects. However not all cases can be handled effectively using Java code. For example, when the xml has duplicate jobParam elements <jobParam type="jobType">Scheduler<jobParam>

Comment: If you cannot redesign the XML, then your options are **(a)** move to XSD 1.1, **(b)** enforce that constraint outside of XSD (in Java, for example), or **(c)** drop the constraint that `jobParam[@type='jobType']` and `jobParam[@type='customer']` must be present.   XSD 1.0 simply cannot express that constraint given the original XML design.  The extra constraint mentioned in your comment is similar.  (Neither should be hard to implement in Java -- just would be nonideal for centralizing validation constraints declaratively in the XSD.)